# jQuery if condition text contains

Tags: javascript, jquery

I wrote a simple if condition, but not quite working.
if text is 123 change to hi, if text is 456 change it to hi2
Could someone please give me a hand.

```
    <h1>123</h1>
    <h1>456</h1>
    <h1>789</h1>​


$(document).ready(function() {

    var changeText1 = '123';
    var changeText2 = '456';
    var text = $(h1).text();

    if (text == changeText) {
        $(this).text('hi');
    } else if (text == changeText2 ) {
        $(this).text('hi2');
    }

});
```

​

http://jsfiddle.net/8P2ma/

Comment: How many of these text substitutions do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple things wrong with your code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var changeText1 = '123';
    var changeText2 = '456';
    var text = $(h1).text(); //aside from having to iterate through, the jquery
                             //selector needs to be enclosed in quotes: $('h1')
    if (text == changeText) { //The variable 'changeText' does not exist.
        $(this).text('hi');
    } else if (text == changeText2 ) {
        $(this).text('hi2');
    }

});

//working code:
$(document).ready(function() {

    var changeText1 = '123';
    var changeText2 = '456';

    $('h1').each(function() {
        var text = $(this).text();
        if (text == changeText1) {
            $(this).text('hi');
        } else if (text == changeText2) {
            $(this).text('hi2');
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: THanks for your explaination and put me up, will tick this to be a right answer.

Comment: @olo Welcome, glad I could assist.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(function() {
    $('h1:contains("123")').text('hi');
    $('h1:contains("456")').text('hi2');
});​
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/rR9Z5/)

Comment: easy and quick, i used contains, but didn't work, I found I missed a letter! thanks for this

Comment: This is way less efficient than either of the other two answers.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var change = {
        '123': 'hi',
        '456': 'hi2'
    };
    $('h1').text(function(i, txt) {
        return change[$.trim(txt)];
    });
});
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/By4Ra/

Comment: This would only work if you can guarantee the order of the elements on the DOM, which seems like a dangerous assumption to make.